# I have confusion take of sales_sequence_profile table in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, table

Can anyone explain where what's the use of this table or where it will work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will be used in the generation of the Increment ID for order, shipment, creditmemo, invoice.